# How to limit access to my wordpress site except for some ip´s?

Tags: wordpress

Hi I need to make a website totally invisible to almost everyone except some ip´s from the company that uses the website. The thing is i can´t a plugin to do what I need. I have some specific ip´s to whitelist and also some ranges. I am not an expert coding or on web design, sorry if my vocabulary is not technically correct. Thanks in advance

Comment: correction: I can´t find a plugin to do what i need.

Also i meant that i have a list with ip´s to whitelist and some ip ranges too.

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Here's an article that indicates how to do what you've asked: https://managewp.com/blog/whitelist-ip-addresses

Comment: Hi Caleb. The thing is i am not tech savy or brave enough to edit the htaccess file. Also the plugin listed in that article doesn´t do what I need, it just whitelist people for the login. Thanks anyway, have a nice day.

Comment: This is a site _for programmers_.  If you are unable to modify the `htaccess` file, then your question is not appropriate for this site.  If you are looking for a plugin, then your question is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to your web files?  If so, all you will need to do is access/modify your `.htaccess` file.

Here are the steps:

1. Download and install [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and select the appropriate download option.  If you are unsure, simply select 'Download FileZilla Client'.
2. Once you have downloaded and installed FileZilla, open it up and login in to your web server.  If you are not sure of your login details, you will need to ask your service provider.  The information you will need, will be

   - Root access username
   - Root access password
   - Host (IP Address)

   **Note:**

   There are 2 ways you can access your web files here.  Firstly, via the top of your opening screen, as per the following diagram:

   [image: FileZilla top bar]

   Do not login this way, as this is insecure, where your credentials can be intercepted.  Alternatively, head to:

   - `File > Site Manager`

   Here, you will find a screen as follows:

   [image: FileZilla site manager]

   Take note of the selection under 'Protocol'.  This will ensure that your credentials are kept secure.

3. Once you have logged in, you then need to find your 'httpdocs' folder.  This will vary upon how your server is setup but would typically within the 'root' folder.
4. Within 'httpdocs', you may find a file entitled `.htaccess`.  If so, drag this over to your computer ready for editing.  If you do not have said file, simply create the file and entitle it `.htaccess`.  You can save it as a 'Normal Text File'.
5. Now that you have created your `.htaccess` file, simply open it and enter the following code:

   ```
   <Files *>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   </Files>
   ```

   Just replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your actual IP address.  You can add as many as you like.  Simply duplicate the 'allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' directly beneath one and other, as is required.
6. Once done, simply save the file and drag it over to your 'httpdocs' folder.  Upon doing this, you should find that the website will only be accessble by people using the designated IP Address(ess).

Comment: looks like this is the way to go. Thanks a lot craig.

Comment: @SantiagoCuellarLeón No worries.  Glad I could be of assistance.  If my answer has solved your problem, do mark it as the accepted answer, to let other people know it worked for you (and so, them). Good luck with your website. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use an ACL (Access Control List) to do the job.
I am not an expert in networks either but maybe you will have to run some ACL commands in your server https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/lan-switching-and-routing/access-list-block-one-ip-or-port-i-just-it-to-stop/td-p/1821639

Answer (score 0):

Try this script

```
    //IP range
    $ip_range_low = ip2long("100.100.100.100");
    $ip_range_high = ip2long("200.200.200.200");

    $white_list_ips = array(
        '10.10.10.10',
        '192.168.1.0',
        '127.0.0.1'
        );

    $ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if ($ip >= $ip_range_low && $ip <= $ip_range_high &&
        !in_array($remote_ip, $white_list_ips) ) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        //Access allowed
    }
```

Take a look at [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function too.